# Can't understand the behaviour of dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, bitset

I am working on a Hill Climber Algorithm and I need to represent data as bitsets.

To sumarize my issue, I have written this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

void print(const boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitset)
{
    std::cout << bitset[0]; //bitset.at(0) - same result

}
int main()
{
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> myBitset(4, 10); // will be 1010
    std::cout << myBitset<<"\n";
    print(myBitset);
    return 0;
}
```

**I can't understand why this prints**

```
1010
0
```

Comment: `bitset[0]` is the LSB, not the MSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, `boost::dynamic_bitset` indexes from the least-significant bit, i.e. the rightmost bit in the usual printed representation of a binary number. So `bitset[0]` is the zero on the far right of `1010`, and the `1` that you expect to be printed is in fact `bitset[3]`.